# Databinding for ExtJs Combobox from Database(Sql)

Tags: asp.net, extjs

How to bind data to ExtJS combo from sql database
(how to assign datatable for extjs combobox as a store)

Answer (score 0):

basic example should be like this:

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  typeAhead: true,
  triggerAction: 'all',
  store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    reader: new Ext.data.JasonReader ( {
       fields: [ 'myId', 'displayText' ],
       root: 'rows'
     }),
     proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy ( {
       url: 'path/to/your/script.aspx'
     } )
  valueField: 'myId',
  displayField: 'displayText'
});
```

where /path/to/your/script.aspx returns data like this:

```
{"success":true,"total":4,"rows":[
  {"myId":"1","displayText":"Option 1"},
  {"myId":"2","displayText":"Option 2"},
  {"myId":"3","displayText":"Option 3"},
  {"myId":"4","displayText":"Option 4"}
]}
```